String extraction does not work on dynamically generated string
Please consider the MWE below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{first_second.tex}
  \ssection
\end{filecontents*}

\def\ssection{%
  % Get the full file name
  \edef\sfilename{\currfilename}%
  
  % Display the current file name for debugging purposes
  \texttt{Current file name: \sfilename} \\

  % \show\sfilename
  
  % Extract the part between underscore and dot
  \StrBetween{\sfilename}{_}{.}[\skey]%

  % \show\StrBetween
  
  % Output the extracted part (if extraction is successful)
  \ifx\skey\empty
    \texttt{Extracted part: (none)}%
  \else
    \texttt{Extracted part: \skey}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\input {first_second.tex}

\end{document}

Instead of getting my expected output, I am getting the extracted string empty.


the catcodes are different, you need either the starred version \StrBetween*{\sfilename}{_}{.}[\skey] or must convert the search chars to strings \StrBetween{\sfilename}{\string_}{\string.}[\skey]

expl3 regular expressions are catcode agnostic.
\begin{filecontents*}{first_second.tex}
  \ssection
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ssection}{}
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_tl \currfilename
  % Display the current file name for debugging purposes
  \texttt{Current~file~name:~\l_tmpa_tl} \par
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {\A [^_]* _ ([^\.]*) \. .* \Z} {\1} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \skey \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \skey
   {
    \texttt{Extracted~part:~(none)}
   }
   {
    \texttt{Extracted~part:~\skey}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\input {first_second.tex}

\end{document}


